# Check assembly's identity? Possibly by it's strong name?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, strongname

In one of my apps I must distinguish my own included addins from others' addins.
They are signed with different keys each and so is the host app.

Is there any way to distinguish my assemblies from others' assemblies? (Possibly with the help of the signing key)

Comment: What is the purpose of distinguishing your assemblies from others' assemblies in this case?  i.e.: In what way(s) will your application treat your assemblies differently from others' assemblies?

Comment: Because my app uses a library that is licensed to me only. Addin developers don't have a license, and, if they do, I'll ask them to contact me.

Comment: If your application has a runtime license, why do you need to police the addins?  If the library developer wants to impose design-time licensing restrictions, then those would presumably apply to the addin developers at design time, but you shouldn't have any additional checks to perform at runtime.

Comment: Take this logically. My App `A` uses library `L` and a developer made the addin `D`. Addins are supposed to USE `A`, which uses `L`. So, `D` uses `L` indirectly! (`A` -> `L` & `D` -> `A` => `D` -> `L`)

Comment: Sure, but if you already have a license to cover the use of L by A at runtime, this license presumably covers all use of L within A, including any addins that might by loaded by A.  This is one of the reasons that component licensing is usually divided into separate runtime and design time rights.  Are you just guessing that L's license doesn't follow this usual pattern, or have you confirmed it with the vendor?

Comment: I have spoken to the marketing director and CTO.

Comment: If their intent is to apply runtime licensing at the assembly level rather than the application level, shouldn't it also be their responsibility to provide the mechanism via which this is implemented?

Comment: @Nicole Calinoiu Mhm... Lemme implement it to protect my license, OK?

Comment: The point is that you don't have the information required to check the runtime license of a third party.  You can try to build a list of supposedly licensed addins, but how will you know that they are really licensed?  Unless they share their license keys with you (which they ought to be very unwilling to do), you won't even be able to reliably verify initial license state.  And you'll definitely have no way of knowing whether their licenses become revoked at some point.  Identifying the source of an assembly at runtime is really the least of your problems here. (cont...)

Comment: That's why the library vendor should at least be providing a mechanism for license state verification at runtime if they expect a licensed application to verify the licensed state of the assemblies that it loads, whether these are add-ins or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your assemblies are signed you can use either `GetPublicKey()` or `GetPublicKeyToken()`

```
 Assembly a =...
 a.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken();

 Assembly a =...
 a.GetName().GetPublicKey();
```

and would be more convenient than keeping list of GUID and would work with future assemblies too.

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: GetPublicKeyToken - returns only 8-bytes token "last 8 bytes of the SHA-1 hash of the public key", second returns the public key.

Comment: So if I use the public key itself it should be more secure?

Comment: Yes, but I think in real life chances even of token coincidence is slim to none.

Comment: As this answer is very simple so I am going to accept it... This is the best option I can find.

Comment: Checking the public key token alone is not sufficient because a) it can easily be acquired and injected by a hacker into their own assembly, and b) the public key token is not a signature of the assembly, it is only a hash of the public key that can easily be duplicated. See [Checking For A Strong Name Signature](http://bit.ly/uDTfKS) for more discussion and a how-to. Note that if you are using .NET 4.0 or above you should use [ICLRStrongName::StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx](http://bit.ly/rw3UC9)

Answer (score 4):

You can check the loaded assembly public key token against the list that is stored in the container assembly.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/19/visual-studio-tip-get-public-key-token-for-a-stong-named-assembly.aspx

Or just simply store the full names of the assemblies like this:

```
var assembly = typeof (string).Assembly;

var myAssemblies = new HashSet<string>
{
 "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
};

Assert.IsTrue(myAssemblies.Contains(assembly.FullName));
```

Also you can check egainst the tokens, using GetPublicKeyToken and BitConverter

```
var assembly = typeof(string).Assembly;

var token = BitConverter.ToString(assembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken()).Replace("-","").ToLowerInvariant();

var expectedToken = "b77a5c561934e089";

Assert.AreEqual(expectedToken, token);
```

Comment: I am curious, can't someone else somehow make assemblies with the same public key?

Comment: if they have the key file, that's why it's normally managed as a securable asset

Comment: It is possible to arbitrarily change the public key token of an assembly to something of your liking. If you just check the PublicKeyToken, you won't be able to detect a fake key.

Comment: @freedompeace: It's possible to valiate a strong name signature in a way that will ignore the verification skips that make loading assemblies with such "fake" signatures possible.

Comment: Hold on a minute... So it IS possible to break/fake the signatures. Then what would be their purpose?

Comment: The public key is 1024 bit by default, not sure it's feasible to find a collision for a fake.

Comment: @Vercas, no. It is possible to fake the value of the `PublicKeyToken` field. The library/pe will run, but it will fail validation. However, testing for only the string match will not validate the signature against the library.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by checking the strong name signature. See [Checking For A Valid Strong Name Signature](http://bit.ly/uDTfKS) for how to this. Note that the article refers to using P/invoke with StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx, but if you are using .NET 4.0 or above you should substitute [ICLRStrongName::StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx](http://bit.ly/rw3UC9).

See [Public Keys and Public Key Tokens](http://bit.ly/rSCump) for what a public key token actually is. Given that it is only a hash of the public key, and therefore easily duplicated or extracted and then injected into an untrusted assembly, it isn't a secure mechanism for validating an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

A little nice snippet:

```
// Assembly is a System.Reflection.Assembly
public string GetAssemblyGUID(Assembly assembly)
{
    object[] objects = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute), false);
    if (objects.Length > 0)
        return ((System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute)objects[0]).Value;
    else
        return null;
}
```

This will retrieve the GUID of the specified assembly. You can set your assembly's GUID in Project Properties. This holds true for class libraries and PEs.

Comment: Ok, so I get the GUID of an addin and check it against my own list. But what prevents another addin from using my own GUIDs?

Comment: @Vercas, nothing. There's no prevention mechanism. It's all "be a good citizen". Let's see... Didn't you say your applications were signed? If they are, why not just check the key signatures? Lastly, you could also just do a hash (MD5, CRC, whatever) of a portion of all assemblies and compare it with your own.

Comment: You need the key file to sign an assembly, and that is (hopefully) kept secret by you.